# Instantiating Object in Parameter Arguments Without using "new"

Tags: c++, oop, object, instantiation

If I want to create a new instance of an object within a parameter argument (in C++), is there a way to do this without using "new". It's my understanding that the use of the "new" keyword means I then have to deal with deleting the object (dynamic allocation?).

Example:

```
wrapper.set_state( new Medium() );
```

Comment: @icbytes Updated the question.

Comment: Does `set_state` actually take a pointer argument? Or is it just an argument of type `Medium`?

Answer (score 2):

As long as `set_state` takes the parameter by const reference, you can construct a temporary value at the call site:

```
void Wrapper::set_state(const & Medium) { ... }

Wrapper wrapper;
wrapper.set_state(Medium());
```

The lifetime of the temporary will extend across `set_state`.

Otherwise, if `set_state` takes a pointer (perhaps it shouldn't!), you need to keep the instance outside of the call:

```
void Wrapper::set_state(Medium*) { ... }

Wrapper wrapper;
{
  // Local block to explicitly manage lifetime of `medium`.
  Medium medium;
  wrapper.set_state(&medium);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the object on the stack (simple call the CTOR without new) -> but the object will be "deleted" after the method returns.

`wrapper.set_state( Medium() );`

Comment: I thought that C++ had a form of garbage collection.

Comment: @MartinRand C++ doesn't have garbage collection, but C++ has a concept of object lifetime and you should leverage C++'s behavior in that respect for your own use. That's why it **has** certain behavior to begin with: it is there to make your life easier. Even though it has no garbage collection, it doesn't mean it doesn't manage resources. C++11 enables you to go very far by leveraging the semantics of values and various kinds of references.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "new" you dynamicly creates and object, that is correct.
when you create an objet using "new" you will need a pointer to "hold" this object and you will access it by that pointer.

In C++11 you have smart pointers. If you use a smart point you dont need to worry about deletes the object. You can find good tutorial on youtube. Search for "Bo Quian"'s tutorial about smart pointers.

If you really like to creates and object that way you coult try to create a function that creates that object for you.